# how to check if a name starts with a certainly letter with a char?

Tags: c#, sorting, char

I have a list with Names and I want to show the whole alphabet and by every letter the right name. like this:

> A
>
> Auernach S.
>
> B
>
> C
>
> Chroma A.
>
> D
>
> Dori K.
>
> E
>
> F

and so on.

so this is my Code right now:

```
for (char letter = 'A'; letter <= 'Z'; letter++) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(letter); 
    Console.ReadKey();

    foreach (var studentName in _student)
    {
        if (studentName.Lastname.StartsWith())
        {

        } 
    }
```

I don't know what to write in the brackets after `StartsWith`. Because of the `char` in the `for` loop. I've tried "letter" or even all the single letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `StartsWith` expects a string, you could call `ToString` on the `letter`.

```
studentName.Lastname.StartsWith(letter.ToString())
```

Another approach it would be to read the first character of the `LastName` and compare it with the `letter`:

```
studentName.LastName[0] == letter
```

In order to make your code more safe, I suggest you make a filtering in the `foreach`:

```
Func<Student, bool> lastNameHasValue = 
    student => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(student?.LastName);

foreach (var studentName in _student.Where(lastNameHasValue))
```

As a side note, the above foreach statement is not very readable. It causes a little confusion to the reader.

- Do you loop through a collection of students? If so why the name of `_student` is not `_students`?
- Are you loop through their names. No. However the variable `var studentName` implies exactly this.

Compare it with this:

```
foreach(var student in students.Where(lastNameHasValue))
```

I bet that the latter is mored readable and meaningful.

Comment: thanks! So the If condition is right? What do I have to write in there? Console.WriteLine?

Comment: @Nathalie you are welcome. You know better than me :) What do you want to print out the last name value. If so Console.WriteLine(studentName.LastName). etc. So figure out what you want and I am pretty sure you can make it.

Comment: yeah. that works! Thank you very much :) I'm a totally beginner, but I guess you already notice haha

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you precompute your student groups by first letter:

```
var studentsByLetter = students.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Lastname))
                               .ToLookup(x => x.Lastname[0]);
```

Then just use the groups:

```
for (char letter = 'A'; letter <= 'Z'; letter++) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(letter);
    Console.ReadKey();
    foreach (var student in studentsByLetter[letter])
    {
        Console.WriteLine(student.Lastname);
    }
}
```